# Yii2: как создать свой класс от ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2, activeform

Я часто использую ActiveForm в своих проектах и это удобно. Написал строку

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'name')->input();?>
```

И у тебя готовое поле с валидацией. Но иногда надо применить маску или что то еще и хотелось бы это правило прописать в модели и что бы ActiveForm это обрабатывал. Например, прописать в rules

```
['phone', 'string', 'max' => 10, 'mask' => '(999) 99-99-999']
```

и оно отработало (сам плагин для маски уже сам подключу).

Как это можно сделать правильно?

Comment: пробовал использовать анонимные функции в рулах?

Comment: Маску для поля через модель не сделаешь, но валидацию прописать можно, есть встроенные валидаторы https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-core-validators/ , тебе подойдет match, чтобы задать паттерн под твой номер. Маску для поля будет проще сделать через js

Answer (score 0):

Создаете свой автономный валидатор. Расширяетесь от `yii\validators\Validator`. Там же реализуете проверку на стороне клиента. Для примера посмотрите как реализован встроенный валидатор [required](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/RequiredValidator.php).

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендовал бы встраивать это в свою отдельную форму. Лучше реализуйте свой `Helper` с набором кастомизированных `input`-ов под все необходимые Вам случаи.

```php
`formFieldsHelper.php`
...
    /**
     * Возвращает activeForm textInput с виджетом Mask с кнопкой очистки
     * @param $form ActiveForm Модель формы
     * @param $model Model Модель
     * @param $attribute string Атрибут модели
     * @param $mask string Regexp выражение для маски виджета (если не указан $alias)
     * @param $labelText string Описание атрибута
     * @param $hintText string Всплывающая подсказка
     * @param $alias string Типовой алиас для виджета, например email (тогда $mask будет сформирован автоматически)
     *
     */
    public function clearableMaskInput($form, $model, $attribute, $mask = '999', $labelText = false, $hintText = null, $alias = null) {
        $options = [
            'placeholder' => false,
            'class' => 'form-control clearable-field'.( is_string($hintText) && trim( $hintText ) != '' ? ' hintable-field' : '' ),
        ];
        $clientOptions = [ 'clearIncomplete' => true  ];
        if ( isset( $alias ) && is_string( $alias ) && trim( $alias ) != '' ) {
            $clientOptions['alias'] = $alias;
            $mask = null;
        }
        $widgetOptions = ['options' => $options,'clientOptions' => $clientOptions];
        if ( !is_null( $mask ) ) {
            $widgetOptions['mask'] = $mask;
        }
        return $form->field($model, $attribute,[
            'template' => "{label}\n{beginWrapper}\n{input}".
                Html::button('', [
                    'class' => 'form-control fad fa-eraser '.( is_null($model->$attribute) || ( is_string($model->$attribute)  && $model->$attribute == '') ? 'disabled ' : 'text-success ').'clear-field-btn',
                    'disabled' => is_null($model->$attribute) || ( is_string($model->$attribute)  && $model->$attribute == ''),
                    'autocomplete' => 'off',
                    'data' => [
                        'toggle' => 'popover',
                        'placement' => 'bottom',
                        'trigger' => 'hover',
                        'html' => 1,
                        'content' => \Yii::t('app', 'Clear'),
                    ],
                ]).( is_string($hintText) && trim( $hintText ) != ''
                    ? Html::button('', [
                    'class' => 'form-control fad fa-question '.( is_null($model->$attribute) || ( is_string($model->$attribute)  && $model->$attribute == '') ? 'disabled ' : 'text-success ').'hint-field-btn',
                    'disabled' => is_null($model->$attribute) || ( is_string($model->$attribute)  && $model->$attribute == ''),
                    'data' => [
                        'toggle' => 'popover',
                        'placement' => 'bottom',
                        'trigger' => 'hover',
                        'html' => 1,
                        'content' => $hintText,
                    ],
                ])
                    : ''

                ).
                "\n{hint}\n{error}\n{endWrapper}",

        ])->widget(MaskedInput::className(), $widgetOptions )->label( $labelText );
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает activeForm textInput с виджетом Mask под ввод телефона с кнопкой очистки
     * @param $form ActiveForm Модель формы
     * @param $model Model Модель
     * @param $attribute string Атрибут модели
     * @param $labelText string Описание атрибута
     * @param $hintText string Всплывающая подсказка
     *
     */
    public function clearablePhoneInput($form, $model, $attribute, $labelText = false, $hintText = null ) {
        return self::clearableMaskInput( $form, $model, $attribute, '(999){1}[-999-99-99]', $labelText, $hintText);
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает activeForm textInput с виджетом Mask под ввод email с кнопкой очистки
     * @param $form ActiveForm Модель формы
     * @param $model Model Модель
     * @param $attribute string Атрибут модели
     * @param $labelText string Описание атрибута
     * @param $hintText string Всплывающая подсказка
     *
     */
    public function clearableEmailInput($form, $model, $attribute, $labelText = false, $hintText = null ) {
        return self::clearableMaskInput( $form, $model, $attribute, null, $labelText, $hintText, 'email');
    }

...
```

вызов

```php
?= FormFieldsHelper::clearableTextInput( $form, $ownerFormModel, '_docno', \Yii::t('owners', 'Field `New Owner\'s Document Number`'), \Yii::t('owners', 'Field `New Owner\'s Document Number` hint') ); ?>
<?= FormFieldsHelper::clearablePhoneInput($form, $ownerFormModel, '_cellphone', \Yii::t('owners', 'Field `New Owner\'s Cell Phone`'), \Yii::t('owners', 'Field `New Owner\'s Cell Phone` hint') ); ?>
<?= FormFieldsHelper::clearableEmailInput($form, $ownerFormModel, '_email', \Yii::t('owners', 'Field `New Owner\'s Email`'), \Yii::t('owners', 'Field `New Owner\'s Email` hint') ); ?>
```

Либо воспользуйтесь встроенным валидатором `match`.

```php
`rules()`
[
                ['_homephone', '_workphone', '_cellphone'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^(\d{3})((\-\d{3})?(\-\d{2})?(\-\d{2})?)?/',
                'message' => \Yii::t('owners', 'Value of field `Phone` is incorrect')               
 ]
```

и виджетом `MaskedInput`

```php
$form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(MaskedInput::className(), ['mask' => '(999) 99-99-999'] );
```